# How to prevent other domanin users from accessing users home directory in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, active-directory, sssd

We have linux (Ubuntu) desktops that are join to a domain using SSSD, i want to restrict users from accessing other users home directory and files for old and new users.
It is possible set this automatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For existing users, `chown go-rwx /home/*` (or wherever the users' home directories are).

For new users, make sure that whatever you're using to auto-create home directories for new users (probably PAM module `pam_mkhomedir.so`?) is configured to create home directories with suitable protection: this can be achieved by adding the `umask=0077` option to the `pam_mkhomedir.so` line.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem

Comment: You don't have enough reputation yet to upvote answers, but you can still mark an answer as *accepted* - it's even better than a regular upvote. Click on the green checkmark just below the voting arrow buttons next to my answer.